# Data copy from Object Storage bucket (scaleway) to aws s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to copy a folder from **object storage bucket** to **AWS S3 bucket**.
Is there any way to do it?

I have tried :

> aws s3 cp s3://scaleway-source-bucket s3://aws-s3-destination bucket

but getting the errors saying that bucket not found.

This is because it's trying to fetch both the buckets from the same configuration.
I have two different configurations - one for scaleway object storage bucket and another for AWS s3 storage bucket.

I need help with this. Is there any way to copy the folder from **scaleway object storage bucket** to **AWS S3 storage bucket**?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `--recursive` to copy folders. See the examples in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html#examples)

> **Recursively copying S3 objects to another bucket**
>
> When passed with the parameter --recursive, the following cp command
>   recursively copies all objects under a specified bucket to another
>   bucket while excluding some objects by using an --exclude parameter.
>   In this example, the bucket mybucket has the objects test1.txt and
>   another/test1.txt:
>
> ```
> aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/ s3://mybucket2/ --recursive --exclude "another/*"
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But issue is I am getting error related to bucket not found.
This is because both are bucket have different accessID and secret keys and aws is looking for credentials and config file and its getting the credentials for only one bucket as I can define only one accessID and secret key in it. 
and when its trying to fetch another bucket which is having different credentails, its not able to find that. so, its throwing error that bucket not found